# jquery and php relations

Tags: php, jquery

how can i store jquery ajax result in a php variable?
i mean i want to get result of ajax jquery and store it in php variable and ECHO it later

Comment: You may get better responses if you go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: I bet you find a lot of questions dealing with jQuery, Ajax and PHP here on SO. Search for them!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this?

What do you mean by "later"? Later, on the same page, or after the user navigates to another page?

If you want to echo it back to the page which has the ajax, then use js/jquery to echo it instead. If you want to save the variable in a session so that you can display it on another page, then you should be doing that on the php page you're presumably calling via ajax, rather than calling a php w/ ajax, having it return something, and then sending it back to the php *again*. However, if you *really* want to do that, you would have to stuff the variable into either a GET or POST variable so that it can be sent back to the server when the user navigates. i.e., put it into a hidden form and force the user to submit it, or put it into a link.... actually, you could do it with a 2nd ajax call, but now we're just going in circles aren't we?

Comment: i want to do that because i want to check if this is an ajax request then reload page to show prev.changes.
it seems that there is no way to do that!
i have to find another way..

Comment: if you want to check if its been requested with ajax, you can look at the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header, or pass a variable along in the ajax call to indicate that it's ajax. instead of reloading the page, make the changes dynamically using js.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use the data argument in the load function 
syntax for load
$('selector').load(url,data,callback)

for data use {'key':'value'}

and then in php use $_REQUESTED